# MikTeX: pdflatex.exe - Entry Point Not Found after the recent update

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I just updated MiKTeX packages in my workstation, and TexWorks gives the following error when I try to make pdf:

> pdflatex.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>   The procedure entry point ?WideCharToUTF8@Utils@Core@MiKTeX@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PB_W@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library MiKTeX209-core.dll.

How can I fix that?

PS: OS - Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, MiKTeX 2.9 32-bit.

Comment: Check for new packages in the manager, run updates as admin and user. See critical updates here.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: Geez. It seems like MikTeX now breaks something with every update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I checked as suggested, but it says no new packages available in both user and admin modes.

Comment: Did you synchronized?

Comment: Yes, first synchronized, then tried to update. Maybe, i can re-install a package which this DLL is coming from?

Comment: I was able to solve it by downloading and re-installing the latest  MikTeX basic distribution. I'm not sure what caused the original issue, but it is solved now.

Comment: If I may intrude, the proposed solution of re-installing MiKTeX when core dll of MiKTeX2.9 get corrupted is simply too extreme. I have the same problem and I have had this problem in November last year also after updating. I did re-install back then, but it took me weeks to get ever package back up and running as required.... Any other way to get these corrupt dlls working?

Comment: I solved this by removing old bin files in C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin\x64 folder. They were not updated, but called anyway because the folder is in path. Trying "where pdflatex.exe" returned  two executables, one ran ok, the other gave the mentioned error.

Comment: @Boocko: I've just run into this problem, and your advice solved it! You should've posted it as an answer -- I would gladly upvote it. Unbeknownst to you, you've just saved my day! (And yes, I know that it's been more than a year since all this was posted here.)