# miktex engines does not work after updating

Tags: miktex

I download the latest miktex installed it. and xetex luatex etc was working great. but after updating engines(pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex) when I use texworks to compile my latex the gives error. also when I start latex.exe in miktex folder it gives same error. the error is:

the procedure entry point

```
?GetWrite18Mode@TeXApp@TeXAndFriends@MiKTeX@@QEBA?AW4S
hellCommandMode@Core@3@XZ could not be located in dynamic link library

c:\users\hossein\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a faulty installation.

Comment: @egreg i uninstalled and installed it again and after updating it happened again

Comment: Why ist pdflatex.exe in AppData? Do you have multiuser or a single user installation?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I complied using pdflatex. I use both multiuser and single user.

Comment: IIRC, you cannot install MikTeX without deleting the original (not just uninstalling it). You might have multiple copies and textworks is linking to the wrong one.

Comment: I too have this problem. I uninstall everything I could find that was MiKTeX related, reinstalled and still get this error. Related post at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309260/miktex-pdflatex-exe-entry-point-not-found-after-the-recent-update?rq=1